# Create IE add on (extension) for take a feedback

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, add-on, bho

I want to develop the add on for IE that will open a feedback form and submit. For Chrome there are many resources but IE I didn`t get any specific example. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Why Internet Explorer? No really, I want to know.

Comment: It was the requirement before, I am just updating the question for the sake of stack overflow policy which is not allowing me to ask further question. #sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You could refer to the following reference to develop IE Add on:

[Sample Internet Explorer add-on: Advanced Search](https://www.add-in-express.com/free-addins/net-internet-explorer-addon.php)

[How to create Internet Explorer add-on in Visual Studio (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsB2uCF657E)

Then, refer to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17447/windows-internet-explorer-11-manage-add-ons) to manage add-ons in Internet Explorer 11

Comment: It is not useful links as I have already visited and nothing found helpful.

Comment: @DT_2 Then don't accept this as an answer.

Comment: Done @Dai thank you for suggestion.